# Criar COLUNM com resultados de uma conta feita dentro de um ROW - MySql

Tags: mysql

Provavelmente o título dessa questão não está correto, o caso é que não saberia como explicar minha dúvida sem um exemplo.

Tenho um cenário onde preciso somar os valores de produtos que ainda não foram entregues, ex:

Meus Registros:
+-----------+------+------------------+------------------+
| Produto  | Qtd. | QtdEntregue | ValorUnitário  |
+-----------+------+------------------+------------------+
|.  Caixa ..|..  5 .. |.......... 2 .........| .....30,00.......|
+-----------+------+------------------+------------------+
|...  Bola...|..  8 .. |.......... 4 .........| .....50,00.......|
+-----------+------+------------------+------------------+

Gostaria que exibisse:
+-----------+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| Produto  | Qtd. | QtdEntregue | ValorUnitário  |   ValorPendente  |
+-----------+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|.  Caixa ..|..  5 .. |.......... 2 .........| .....30,00.......|........90,00.........|
+-----------+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|...  Bola...|..  8 .. |.......... 4 .........| .....50,00.......|  .......200,00.......|
+-----------+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+

Basicamente, preciso adicionar uma `COLUNM` em cada `ROW` fazendo um determinado calculo para exibir o resultado:
- `COLUMN` "ValorPendente" exibindo Valor Restante de Produto a que não foram entregues:
**Qtd - QtdEntregue * ValorUnitário = ValorPendente**

E como somar todos estes valores após a exibição ?
não creio que o `SUM(ValorPendente)` Servirá para este caso.

Comment: Isso seria um select ? ou vc que criar uma coluna mesmo na sua tabela?

Comment: Apenas uma exibição, um Select, sem ser necessário armazenar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer isso em um `SELECT`, bas fazer uma `query` como esta:

```
SELECT Produto, Qtde, QtdeEntregue, ValorUnitario, ((Qtd - QtdEntregue) * ValorUnitário) ValorPendente
FROM sua_tabela
```

Mas se você quiser criar um campo na sua tabela para armazenar isso via `MySQL`, será necessário criar uma `TRIGGER`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, não preciso armazenar, apenas exibir mesmo.

Comment: Existe uma maneira de somar estes valores ? Talvez atravéz de um ExecuteScalar ?

Comment: Tem sim, coloque um `SUM` antes, desta forma: `SELECT Produto, Qtde, QtdeEntregue, ValorUnitario, SUM(((Qtd - QtdEntregue) * ValorUnitário)) ValorPendente
FROM sua_tabela`, não precisa do `ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 1):

Basta você fazer o que você já fez na pergunta, ou seja.

```
select (Qtd - QtdEntregue) * ValorUnitário as 'ValorPendente'
from MyTabela
```

e se que o valor total basta somar.

```
select sum((Qtd - QtdEntregue) * ValorUnitário) as 'ValorPendenteTotal'
from MyTabela
```